# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum for PNG creates random image in transparent parts of thumbnail (ONLY)

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, uiimage, png

I have some well-working code for reading the screen or offscreen buffer and saving the result to the iPad photo album as a PNG with transparency.  The images appear perfectly when viewed in the ipad photo viewer or any other image viewer.  However, within ipad's native photo viewing app the **thumbnails** show portions of other images from the album in the transparent sections of the thumbnail.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, and if so found a fix for it?  Here's my offscreen (partial) code for generating the images:

```
EAGLContext *myContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:myContext];

[... set up render buffer code removed for display ...]

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:myContext];

ImageTextureManager *imageManager = [[ImageTextureManager alloc] init];
[imageManager loadImageTexture:gAppModel.currentImageRef];
[imageManager release];

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, offscreenColorRenderbuffer);

[self renderTransformedImage]; // render the image to the buffer

[myContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];

// grab image from frameBuffer and return it as UIImage
NSInteger x = 0, y = 0;
NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace,
                                kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height), iref);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  // this call creates an AutoRelease UIImage
NSData* imdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); // get PNG representation
UIImage* myImagePNG = [UIImage imageWithData:imdata]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImagePNG, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thanks to medvedNick for his offscreen rendering code: [Drawing into OpenGL ES framebuffer and getting UIImage from it on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936157/drawing-into-opengl-es-framebuffer-and-getting-uiimage-from-it-on-iphone)

Comment: just to clarify, the "random" parts in the thumbnail are always from some other image in the album (i.e. the effect is that my desired image appears overlaid on top of some other random image from the album)

Comment: also, the problem only shows up on the iPad hardware.  it does not show up in the simulator. (app is not iPhone compatible)