# iOS OpenGL ES 2.0: Offscreen render and save the result to an UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using OpenGL ES to render some special effects, I don't want to show this to user, I just want to save the result as an UIImage, can anybody please help me?

this is the code I'm using, I can get an image which contains the red clear color I use, but no geometry drawing shown.

```
#import "RendererGL.h"
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

static NSInteger WIDTH_IN_PIXEL = 400;
static NSInteger HEIGHT_IN_PIXEL = 300;

typedef struct {
    GLKVector3 positionCoords;
}
SceneVertex;

static const SceneVertex vertices[] =
{
    {{-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0}}, // lower left corner
    {{ 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0}}, // lower right corner
    {{-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0}}  // upper left corner
};

@implementation RendererGL
{
    EAGLContext* _myContext;

    GLuint _framebuffer;
    GLuint _colorRenderbuffer;
    GLuint _depthRenderbuffer;

    GLuint _vertexBufferID;

    GLKBaseEffect *_baseEffect;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _myContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_myContext];
        [self setupOffscreenBuffer];
        [self setUpEffect];
        [self renderImage];
        [self saveImage];  //this do works, since I get an image, but the image only contains the red color I used to clear
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)setUpEffect
{
    _baseEffect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    _baseEffect.useConstantColor = GL_TRUE;
    _baseEffect.constantColor = GLKVector4Make(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
}

//this code is from apples document
-(void)setupOffscreenBuffer
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, WIDTH_IN_PIXEL, HEIGHT_IN_PIXEL);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderbuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, WIDTH_IN_PIXEL, HEIGHT_IN_PIXEL);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderbuffer);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
    }
}

- (void) renderImage
{
    GLenum error = GL_NO_ERROR;

    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);   //red clear color, this can be seen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    [_baseEffect prepareToDraw];

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        NSLog(@"error happend, error is %d, line %d",error,__LINE__);
    }

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(SceneVertex),  NULL);                   
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        NSLog(@"error happend, error is %d, line %d",error,__LINE__);
    }

    glFinish();
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        NSLog(@"error happend, error is %d, line %d",error,__LINE__);
    }
}

-(void)saveImage
{
    GLenum error = GL_NO_ERROR;

    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0;
    NSInteger dataLength = WIDTH_IN_PIXEL * HEIGHT_IN_PIXEL * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, WIDTH_IN_PIXEL, HEIGHT_IN_PIXEL, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    NSData *pixelsRead = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:dataLength];

    error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        NSLog(@"error happend, error is %d, line %d",error,__LINE__);
    }

    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(WIDTH_IN_PIXEL, HEIGHT_IN_PIXEL, 8, 32, WIDTH_IN_PIXEL * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                    ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(WIDTH_IN_PIXEL, HEIGHT_IN_PIXEL));
    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, WIDTH_IN_PIXEL, HEIGHT_IN_PIXEL), iref);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    NSData *d = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    NSString *documentDirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    static NSInteger imageNO = 1;
    imageNO++;
    NSString *savingPath = [documentDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",imageNO]];
    BOOL succ = [d writeToFile:savingPath atomically:NO];   //is succeeded

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
}

@end
```

Comment: Why did you create an NSData object named pixelsRead, and then never use it anywhere?

Comment: Can you share your code please?? Actually how do you pass your image object to your this class?? And what is the super class of RendererGL class?

Comment: How do use it to draw in glkview??

Answer (score 6):

I had a very similar problem - to render some lines and get UIImage. I used OpenGL ES 1.1 and multisampling. I removed some additional code that does not refers to rendering and some OpenGL error checks. You can find the full code here: [OSPRendererGL](https://github.com/medvedNick/Mapsforge_iOS/blob/master/OpenStreetPad/OpenStreetPad/OSPRendererGL.m). Also, sorry for my one-for-all method.

```
@interface OSPRendererGL
{
    EAGLContext* myContext;
    GLuint framebuffer;
    GLuint colorRenderbuffer;
    GLuint depthRenderbuffer;
    GLuint _vertexArray;
    GLuint _vertexBuffer;
    GLuint resolveFramebuffer;
    GLuint msaaFramebuffer, msaaRenderbuffer, msaaDepthbuffer;

    int width;
    int height;
}

@implementation OSPRendererGL

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        myContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:myContext];
        [self setupOpenGL];
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
        width = 256;
        height = 256;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setupOpenGL
{
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);

    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &msaaFramebuffer); 
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &msaaRenderbuffer);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, msaaFramebuffer); 
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaRenderbuffer);   

    glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height); 
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaRenderbuffer); 

    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &msaaDepthbuffer);   
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaDepthbuffer); 
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, width, height); 
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaDepthbuffer);

}

-(UIImage *) renderImageAtZoom:(int)zoom
{
    CGRect b = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    OSPCoordinateRect r = OSPRectForMapAreaInRect([self mapArea], b);

    double_scale = b.size.width / r.size.x;
    double scale = 1.0/_scale;

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:myContext];

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, msaaFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaRenderbuffer);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrthof(0.0f, 256.0f, 256.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glPushMatrix();

    glScalef(_scale, _scale, 1);
    glTranslatef(-r.origin.x, -r.origin.y, 0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // rendering here

    glPopMatrix();

    // msaa

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, msaaFramebuffer); 
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, framebuffer);

    glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

    // grabbing image from FBO

    GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                    ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height), iref);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a call to eglSwapBuffers().  That is required to start rendering the frame on PowerVR, even when rendering to a Renderbuffer.  See the example code at:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Render_to_Texture_with_OpenGL_ES

Comment: PowerVR has a deferred rendering design, which basically means it does not begin rendering the frame until eglSwapBuffers() is called.  This is done in case there could be additional calls to glDrawArrays() that could be consolidated.  The EGL driver understands that the RenderBuffer is not double-buffered, but you still must call it, unless it's done somewhere else already, like the PVRShell, for example.

Comment: @ClayMontgomery OpenGL ES 2.0 seems have no such method as eglSwapBuffers(), what should I do?

Comment: @ClayMontgomery - The deferred rendering kicks in on any `glReadPixels()` operation, so this doesn't need to be called manually on iOS. Execution will block at that point until the deferred rendering is completed, then pixels will be read.

Comment: egl is not part of iOS.

Comment: OK, Thanks.  That's good to know.  I am a Linux/Android guy, but I think the example code at the link I posted could still be helpful as a working reference on PowerVR.  You also have not setup the Viewport for the dimensions of the RenderBuffer.